# Module QtQuick 2.2 not installed when run in android

Tags: android, qt

I installed qt-opensource-linux-x64-android-5.2.1.run to build a QML project with. I imported QtQuick 2.2 in my main .qml file. I my project against the installed /opt/qt-5.2.1-android. I installed the .apk into a 2013 Nexus 7. The error I saw was:

```
W/Qt      (17431): util/qdeclarativeview.cpp:546 (void QDeclarativeView::continueExecute()): qrc:/multi_page_app.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" version 2.2 is not installed
```

I also tried building with /opt/qt-5.3.0-android, but it resulted in the same error. I must be missing something. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my build script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/opt/android-ndk-r9d
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk

export PATH=/opt/qt-5.2.1-android/5.2.1/android_armv7/bin:${PATH}

export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk

export ANT_HOME=/usr/bin/ant

qmake
make install INSTALL_ROOT=android-build
androiddeployqt --output android-build
```

Here's my .pro file:

```
QT += declarative qml quick widgets

SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += multi_page_app.qrc
```

Here's my .qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Multi Screen App")
    width: 1200
    height: 1920
}
```

Here's my main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeView>
#include <QQuickView>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/multi_page_app.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here's my .qrc file:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">

<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>multi_page_app.qml</file>
</qresource>

</RCC>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. Somehow in my research I got a little wrapped around the axle in my `main.cpp`. I was using `QDeclarativeView` instead of `QQuickView`. The `QDeclarativeView` is for use with the older `QtQuick`. The `QQuickView` is for use with the newer `QtQuick 2.x`. So, here is my new `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickView>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/multi_page_app.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```